# Creating XDocument based on existing XML file

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create XDocument based on existing XML file and use it with TreeView. I want to group contacts by the Group element.

XML file  structure -

```
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
    <First_Name>Ren</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Fuji</Last_Name>
    <Group>Test</Group>
    <Home_Number>Unavailable</Home_Number>
    <Mobile_Number>Unavailable</Mobile_Number>
    <Image></Image>
  </Contact>
<Contacts>
```

Here is the method which creates XDocument object -

```
     static XDocument groupXDoc = new XDocument();
     private static void CreateGroupsXML()
            {
                XElement root = new XElement("Groups");
                groupXDoc.Add(root);
                foreach (XElement xelement in xdoc.Element("Contacts").Elements("Contact").ToList())
                {
                    String groupData = (String)xelement.Element("Group").Value;
                    XElement groups = new XElement("Group", new XAttribute("Name", groupData));
                    root.Add(groups);
                    if (groupXDoc.Root.Element("Group").FirstAttribute.Value == xelement.Element("Group").Value)
                    {
                        groups.Add(new XElement("First_Name", (String)xelement.Element("First_Name").Value),
                            new XElement("Last_Name", (String)xelement.Element("Last_Name").Value),
                            new XElement("Home_Number", (String)xelement.Element("Home_Number").Value),
                            new XElement("Mobile_Number", (String)xelement.Element("Mobile_Number").Value)
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
```

However that's the result I'm getting -

[image]

As you can see only the first contact shows correctly, but the other two doesn't. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static XDocument GroupContactsByGroupField(XDocument doc)
    {
        var contacts = doc.Descendants("Contact").Select(x => new
        {
            FirstName = x.Element("First_Name").Value,
            LastName = x.Element("Last_Name").Value,
            Group = x.Element("Group").Value,
            HomeNumber = x.Element("Home_Number").Value,
            MobileNumber = x.Element("Mobile_Number").Value
        });
        var contactsGroupedByGroup = contacts.GroupBy(x => x.Group);

        var newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Groups", contactsGroupedByGroup.Select(x =>
           new XElement("Group", new XAttribute("Name", x.Key),
            x.Select(y => new XElement("Contact",
                new XElement("First_Name", y.FirstName),
                new XElement("Last_Name", y.LastName),
                new XElement("Home_Number", y.HomeNumber),
                new XElement("Mobile_Number", y.MobileNumber)
            ))))));
        return newDoc;
    }
```